# Assets are not compiled on the Development Level of Ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem to work with my environment on the development level. I dont understand why `Application.css.scss` is not showing up on the front. I mean that ruby is not putting files from `app` instead it taking files from `public/assets`. So when I putting any styles to `scss` it doesn't adding them at all. I dont have nothing specific in the gemfile.

Application.css.scss

```
/*
  *= require_self
  *= require fonts
  *= require styles
  *= require_tree .
*/
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
....
```

Comment: Is your stylesheet file named `Application.css.scss` or `application.css.scss`? It's typically named `application.css.scss`. Which is referenced by `stylesheet_link_tag` in your view? Is the file in `app/assets/stylesheets` or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your assets locally into `public/assets`, Rails will use those file instead of what you have in `app/assets`. To fix it, just remove `public/assets` directory.

Comment: What do you mean just remove them directory? I removed them with 'clobber' and it's still not reading from 'app' it even doesn't show up in the inspector.